# One table or duplicate table with same properties but different dependencies

Tags: sql-server, database-design, entity-framework

**Disclaimer:** I'm new to database modeling so I apologize in advance if the question is unclear or causes any confusion.

I am using .NET Entity Framework and have the following tables:

[image: ERD]

An **Order** can have multiple **Items**, but **Item** itself is not existence dependent on **Order**. That said, should I have two separate tables for **Item**, e.g. **InventoryItem** and **OrderItem**? If not, how should I manage the relationship?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely separate them as they represent different concepts. An invevtory item is a count of stock on hand and mirrors physical artefacts. An order item is a clause in a contract of sale. The order item may or may not be honoured, amended or have a different product substituted. It only gains anything like physical representation when a shipment and corresponding shipment items are created.

Each of these "item" tables will have a foreign key to a Product table. Each represents the intersection of Product and some header table resolving a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your explanation, but I'm confused about the many-to-many relationship. Do you mean that, say, inventory item and order item should have a many-to-many relationship, which is associated by the Product table, with a common header table to hold common properties/attributes?

Comment: No. There is a many-to-many between Order and Product which is resolved by OrderItem. The same with Shipment / ShipmentItem and StorageLocation / InventoryItem.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a many to many relationship it's better to introduce a table which holds the relationship between the two tables which is much more normalized.